# accessing a file using [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: ofType:inDirectory:

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, filepath, nsbundle

I have a file `paylines.txt` added inside the folder named `TextFiles` which resides inside the `Resources` folder of my iOS project in Xcode.

This is the code I use to access the file:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"paylines" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"TextFiles"];
NSLog(@"\n\nthe string %@",filePath);
```

The code prints:

```
2011-06-07 14:47:16.251 slots2[708:207] 

the string  (null)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well i found out the mistake i was committing i was adding a group to the project instead of adding real directory for more [instructions](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/31256-nsbundle-pathforresource-indirectory-gives-nil.html)

Comment: Yes, as it is said in the link: In the pop-up window make sure you select "Create Folder References for any added folders" instead of "Create groups for any added folders"

Answer (score 167):

I was also having the same problem.
The Solution i found is  ( in xcode 4.x):

**Go to :  Target -> "Build Phases" -> "copy  bundle Resources"
Then add that particular file here.**
**If that file is already added , delete it and add it again.**

**clean the project and RUN. It works.**  :)

Comment: For me the file was there, so I deleted it and added it again, cleaned and it worked!

Comment: In my case, somehow the 'Add to Targets' checkbox for my app was unchecked; didn't realize it until I deleted the file and then added it again. Oops!

Comment: Emphasizing comments from others and other similar answers: sometimes you do this right and it still doesn't work. If so, be sure to remove the file from the bundle in that Project pane (BuildPhases/Bundle Resources), and then re-add it. And then Project>Clean. That finally worked for me!

Comment: yes, also had to delete it and re-add to get it to work. thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Try this, it's working for me.

```
NSString *str = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"paylines.txt"];
```

For simulator

```
NSURL *rtfUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"paylines" withExtension:@".txt"];
```

Answer (score 10):

When I drag files in, the "Add to targets" box seems to be un-ticked by default. If I leave it un-ticked then I have the problem described. Fix it by deleting the files then dragging them back in but making sure to tick "Add to targets".
[image]

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is make sure that the checkbox shown below is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you attempting to do this inside of an XCTest and on the verge of smashing your laptop? This is the thread for you: [Why can't code inside unit tests find bundle resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879247/why-cant-code-inside-unit-tests-find-bundle-resources)

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Target" -> "Build Phases", select your target, select the “Build Phases” tab, click “Add Build Phase”, and select “Add Copy Files”. Change the destination to “Products Directory”. Drag your file into the “Add files” section.

Comment: if you could also tell me what i did to have this file removed from the copy files list, i would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In case of Mac OSX,

Go to Targets -> Build Phases 
click + to Copy new files build phases
Select product directory and drop the file there.

Clean and run the project.

Answer (score 1):

After following @Neelam Verma's answer or @dawid's answer, which has the same end result as @Neelam Verma's answer, difference being that @dawid's answer starts with the drag and drop of the file into the Xcode project and @Neelam Verma's answer starts with a file already a part of the Xcode project, I still could not get `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file-title", ofType:"type")` to find my video file.

I thought maybe because I had my file was in a Group nested in the Xcode project that this was the cause, so I moved the video file to the root of my Xcode project, still no luck, this was my code:

```
 guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testVid1", ofType:"mp4") else {
        print("Invalid video path")
        return
    }
```

Originally, this was the name of my file: `testVid1.MP4`, renaming the video file to `testVid1.mp4` fixed my issue, so, at least the `ofType` string argument is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Select Project / Specific Folder --> Right Click --> Add Files to Project -- > Select the File you want to add.

This worked for me.