# Having trouble reading sqlite file

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, local-files

What im trying to do is to read data from my own sqlite file.

My app is allowing me to make a sqlite file and then read from it but if I add the file "asg.sqlite" it wont read from it it only if i have my app create the sqlite file first can i then read from it. Its racking my brain please help here is my code

```
-(void) createTable: (NSString *) tableName
         withField1:(NSString *) field1
         withField2:(NSString *) field2
         withField3:(NSString *) field3
         withField4:(NSString *) field4;
{
    char *err;
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ('%@' "" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' TEXT);", tableName, field1, field2, field3, field4 ];

    if(sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)
       != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"table created");
    }
}
//file path to database
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"asg.sqlite"
            ];
}

//open the database
-(void)openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that if you add you db file in the bundle, it won't be in the Documents directory. You will find it in the main bundle of the app.  use

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:....
```

[This question can help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263289/accesing-a-file-using-nsbundle-mainbundle-pathforresource-oftypeindirectory)

Comment: Could be. If you drag a file into the xcode project, it won't be on the Documents folder of the app but in the bundle