# UIWebView not displaying HTML

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have searched on S/O and none of the answers have applied to my code so I am assuming its something I am missing in my code.

I added a `UIWebView` using Interface Builder called showAbout

I declared an iVar with an IBOutlet here:

```
@interface About : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
{
   IBOutlet UIWebView *showAbout;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *showAbout;
```

I verified that InterfaceBuilder does in fact have an outlet set for it.

Here is how I am setting it up in the about.m

```
 showAbout.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"];
    if (thePath) {
        NSData *aboutData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        [showAbout loadData:aboutData MIMEType:@"application/html"
                        textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

The UIWebView is not displaying my HTML page that I have added to the project.

Any ideas...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263289/accesing-a-file-using-nsbundle-mainbundle-pathforresource-oftypeindirectory may be your problem.

Comment: @PaulCezanne, I didnt set up this bounty from my mac... will check tonight and advise.

Comment: @PaulCezanne  aboutData is not nil. It actually finds the html file because it shows 118 bytes. (or its finding some file)

Comment: Thank you all for helping out with this. It turns out it was a very easy MIME Type issue. Though the changing it to an NSString was an option, the MIME type change offered by @omz was the best solution for me because it was the least amount of code to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct [MIME type for HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_text) is `text/html`, not `application/html`, so you should use that for the `MIMEType` argument.

Alternatively, you could also convert your `NSData` object to an `NSString` and use the `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method of `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 3):

probably it is better to use NSString and load html document as follows:

**ViewController.h file**

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

*make sure that property is connected to webView in XIB/StoryBoard*

**ViewController.m file**

```
 NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

In .h file you need initial a webview outlet

```
    IBOutlet UIWebView *_wvSetting;
```

In .m file

```
        NSString htmlContent = nil;
        htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        [_wvSetting loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil];
```