# Nil return value from fileURLWithPath

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, directory, nsurl

I've recently completed an app-project which mainly consisted of html-files in a webView.

Now I set up another project and copied the relevant code-fragments, but the app crashes with this error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

this is the code:

```
NSString *path01 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01-a" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"htdocs"];
NSURL *url01 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path01];
NSURLRequest *request01 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url01];
[webView01 loadRequest:request01];
```

I guess the problem is the file-reference, but everything is in its place, but the result is always NIL.

I´ve searched for the problem, it seems there is something wrong with how i imported the files to xcode, but i can´t fix it. Is there a simple trick to get xcode to properly import the folder "htdocs"?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Xcode doesn't return anything; it's an IDE, not a method. This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263289/accesing-a-file-using-nsbundle-mainbundle-pathforresource-oftypeindirectory)?

Comment: Yeah, right, but since the problem occurs in xcode and there is clearly something wrong with the reference in xcode, the tag was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file 01-a.html is copied to your app bundle. This can be achieved via the Copy Files / Copy bundled resources phase when building the app. The crash indicates, that the file is missing from the bundle and thus a nil value is returned. You should do checks for nil in such cases.

Comment: Heck, it worked. Thanks. But i still don´t understand what happened, because i did exactly the same before (at least 2 times).

Comment: Maybe a Clean Build would have already helped then. Sometimes voodoo happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url01 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path01];
```

The only parameter is `path01`, so let's see where that comes from

```
NSString *path01 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01-a" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"htdocs"];
```

That means you don't have a file `htdocs/01-a.html` in your resources.

Note that xcode flattens resource structure so you probably just want to drop the `inDirectory` argument.

Comment: Thanks, there was some confusion while importing the directory, it wasn´t copied into the bundle. It works just fine now.