# Path to file in app bundle

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, nsxmlparser

I did this many times before but now it fails.
I want to access a file shipped within my app.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"information" ofType:@"xml"];
```

returns

```
/Users/eldude/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5969FF96-7023-4859-90C0-D4D03D25998D/App.app/information.xml
```

which is correct - checked in terminal and all that. However, trying to parse the path fails

```
    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

    [nsXmlParser setDelegate:self];

    if(![nsXmlParser parse]){
        NSError* e = nsXmlParser.parserError;
        NSLog(@"ERROR parsing XML file: \n %@",e);
        self = NULL;
    }
```

with

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)" UserInfo=0xb9256f0 {NSXMLParserErrorMessage=Could not open data stream}
```

Ideas anyone?

Comment: The answer fro néelam:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263289/accesing-a-file-using-nsbundle-mainbundle-pathforresource-oftypeindirectory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

File URLs and network URLs are different.
From the Apple documentation:

Important: To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use
`fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`
or just
`fileURLWithPath:`

Example:

```
NSString *filePath = @"path/file.txt";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSLog(@"fileURL: %@", [fileURL absoluteURL]);

NSURL *netURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
NSLog(@"netURL: %@", [netURL absoluteURL]);
```

NSLog Output:
fileURL: file:///path/file.txt
netURL: path/file.txt