# Objective-c NSInvalidArgumentException Xcode7

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hey Guys I'm just gonna cut to the chase I was trying to play audio

```
- (IBAction)click1:(id)sender{
    Drill.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Drillx2"];
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID);
}

- (IBAction)click2:(id)sender
{    
    Drill.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Drillx1"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Drill" ofType:@"m4a"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And I get this error

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Thanks,
Derek

**Note :** Yes the resource for the sound is named Drill.

Comment: Pyro deleted the solution but you can find it at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263289/accesing-a-file-using-nsbundle-mainbundle-pathforresource-oftypeindirectory Thanks @Pyro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code

```
NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Drill" ofType:@"m4a"]];
```

It didn't find the given file in the bundle file path. 
 make sure you have added file in the proper target and also build again after adding the resource to make sure it exist in the bundle

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initFileURLWithPath:) : As written in the parameter `Passing nil for this parameter produces an exception.`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d70e695e2e0ae23e959f3a160fa33edb Here is part of my code and where my sound is located. Still doesn't Run :(. Please Help

Comment: `NSString* movieFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"video_1" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFilePath];` 
Try this code if this works

Comment: I Still get the same exact error. I can't seem to find this error with audio anywhere. Edit: Oh and by the way its a "m4a" not a "mp4"

Comment: ok , you can check for some outher solution if it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263289/accesing-a-file-using-nsbundle-mainbundle-pathforresource-oftypeindirectory

Comment: i have taken that from my sample code so i have keep it as MP4, hope your issue is solved