# NSBundle path file returns nil

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsbundle

My app needs to read a text file so I added the file to the project folder, using "Copy Bundle Resources" in the "Build Phases" of the test target. I can see the file in the Xcode project structure, but when I debug the app, it shows the string is `nil`. I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157480/nsbundle-pathforresource-returns-nil) but it didn't solve this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add the file to the specific target?

Comment: I guess you should add the txt file to the `Copy Files` build phase (create one if it's not present) instead of the `Copy Bundle Resource` phase of the appropriate target

Comment: Thanks #Daniel Nagy that worked.