# Xcode: how to test main bundles .plist file content?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

I'd like to ensure with unit tests that important values inside my main `MyApp-Info.plist` are there and correct. Is there a way to load that plist from within my unit test bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on if you have set a host application for your test target. If there is no host application, then the file is not copied with the test.

If there is a host application you can get its plist contents with:

Swift:

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary
```

Objective-C:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include your Info.plist in the Unit test bundle as a resource as well. That way, there's no dependency on the host application. However, finding and loading the resource requires just a tiny bit of trickery that seems to always trip me up.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151420/load-files-in-xcode-unit-tests) for examples on how to do that from ObjC and Swift.