# How do I access a certain info.plist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist

I have multiple `info.plist` files and would like to access them programatically. I read here how this could be done:

https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-read-info-plist/

But when I try:

```
let infoPlistPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Myplist-Info", withExtension: "plist")
print(infoPlistPath)
```

it returns nil.

I have tried adding the `plist` to the respective target with the same result.
I have also tried adding the `plist` to the setting `copy bundle resource`. But it still returns nil.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Is that the real name of your plist file? Case sensitive, etc? Could you screenshot your XCode view?

Comment: No it's not, I just wrote something else here on SO because of company policies and so on. I have tried multiple info.plist files and it's all the same... If it helps, I'm trying to access them in a unitTest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151420/load-files-in-xcode-unit-tests ?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried putting it outside of the test in a regular viewController and it's the same thing :/ still nil

Comment: Compile the app then open the IPA file: are the plist files in there? Easy way to test if the files are properly copied in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached the code to get all properties of Info.plist.

```
func getDataFromInfoPlist(){
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist") {
       let infoListValue = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        do {
            let JsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: infoListValue as Any, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let val = NSString(data: JsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
            print(val)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
    print(nsDictionary as Any)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same. All info.plist files return nil...