# Info.plist specific to a test target

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have two targets, my main target and my test target that uses OCUnit.
Both targets are pointing at a different info.plist in each target build settings.
I wanted to add custom info.plist settings to my test target, but once i run the project and call

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FooKey"];
```

But it does not find it.

If i try to look for the test target plist it also doesn't find it

```
NSString *fooPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"fooInfo" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Even if i add the info.plist to the "Copy Bundle Resources" in "Build Phases".

Does anyone know how could I have add custom properties to an infoPlist just for tests? I wanted to do this so I wouldn't have to point to a specific File.

Thanks

**Edit:**

Thanks @aminoacid for your reply, question is duplicated of [Why can't code inside unit tests find bundle resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879247/why-cant-code-inside-unit-tests-find-bundle-resources)

which in result for future reference:

```
 [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyTestClass class]] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"fooKey"]
```

will provide the required answer.

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879247/why-cant-code-inside-unit-tests-find-bundle-resources

Comment: @Aminoacids thanks for your reply, should have done at first, thank you so much:D