# NSBundle mainBundle in test returns nil even though bundle resource is copied

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I'm writing some tests with [Specta/Expecta](https://github.com/specta) and have created a fresh Test target for my project. As part of one of the tests, I need to validate that certain files from a **Folder Reference** exist.

In my main target, I can do this and it locates the file as expected:

```
NSString* appJson = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ActionSheetTest" ofType:@"json"];
```

In my test target however, I cannot (`appJson` is `nil`). I've added the folder `Tests` to my "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Test target as seen below, but it still doesn't load. What am I doing wrong? I've also tried setting `pathForResource` to `Tests/Controls/ActionSheetTest` (which actually makes more sense to me) but that doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: aha! [Why can't code inside unit tests find bundle resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879247/why-cant-code-inside-unit-tests-find-bundle-resources)