# Set 'Host Application' to None for test target, then unable to find bundle resources

Tags: ios, unit-testing, storyboard, xctest, nsbundle

Before setting Host Application to none, I had this line of code in my unit tests which gave me no problems.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
```

After setting it to None, I got this error.

```
<unknown>:0: failed: caught “NSInvalidArgumentException”, “Could not find a
storyboard named ‘Main’ in bundle NSBundle 
</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin> (loaded)”
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879247/why-cant-code-inside-unit-tests-find-bundle-resources) which gave me the solution. I just specified the bundle of the class I was loading the view controller in like this.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```

I'm just wondering why this happens. What is happening when I remove the Host Application that causes resources from the main bundle to get excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I figured out why. Documentation for mainBundle says

> Returns the NSBundle object that corresponds to the directory where the current application executable is located.

Since I removed Host Application, my project couldn't find main bundle directory because there's no application executable.

Comment: I have often wondered what 'Host Application' did and saw no change, because I'm used to writing my test code the second way. Now I know!