# Use resources in unit tests with Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to use a resource file in unit tests and access it with `Bundle.path`, but it returns nil.

This call in MyProjectTests.swift returns nil:

```
Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "TestAudio", ofType: "m4a")
```

Here is my project hierarchy. I also tried moving `TestAudio.m4a` to a `Resources` folder:

```
├── Package.swift
├── Sources
│   └── MyProject
│       ├── ...
└── Tests
    └── MyProjectTests
        ├── MyProjectTests.swift
        └── TestAudio.m4a
```

Here is my package description:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyProject",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyProject",
            targets: ["MyProject"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyProject",
            dependencies: []
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyProjectTests",
            dependencies: ["MyProject"]
        ),
    ]
)
```

I am using Swift 4 and the Swift Package Manager Description API version 4.

Comment: Have you figured how to handle this with the Xcode 11 GM+?

Comment: Didn't try. Sorry !

Comment: @Hugal31 you should change the accepted answer, seeing how it's supported now

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Swift 5.3+**

See Apple Documentation: ["Bundling Resources with a Swift Package"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package)

*Swift 5.3 includes [Package Manager Resources SE-0271](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0271-package-manager-resources.md) evolution proposal with "Status: **Implemented (Swift 5.3)**".*

> Resources aren't always intended for use by clients of the package; one use of resources might include test fixtures that are only needed by unit tests. Such resources would not be incorporated into clients of the package along with the library code, but would only be used while running the package's tests.
>
> - Add a new `resources` parameter in `target` and `testTarget` APIs to allow declaring resource files explicitly.
>
> SwiftPM uses file system conventions for determining the set of source files that belongs to each target in a package: specifically, a target's source files are those that are located underneath the designated "target directory" for the target. By default this is a directory that has the same name as the target and is located in "Sources" (for a regular target) or "Tests" (for a test target), but this location can be customized in the package manifest.

> ```swift
> // Get path to DefaultSettings.plist file.
> let path = Bundle.module.path(forResource: "DefaultSettings", ofType: "plist")
>
> // Load an image that can be in an asset archive in a bundle.
> let image = UIImage(named: "MyIcon", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))
>
> // Find a vertex function in a compiled Metal shader library.
> let shader = try mtlDevice.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: Bundle.module).makeFunction(name: "vertexShader")
>
> // Load a texture.
> let texture = MTKTextureLoader(device: mtlDevice).newTexture(name: "Grass", scaleFactor: 1.0, bundle: Bundle.module, options: options)
> ```

**Example**

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "Example",
      dependencies: [],
      resources: [
        // Apply platform-specific rules.
        // For example, images might be optimized per specific platform rule.
        // If path is a directory, the rule is applied recursively.
        // By default, a file will be copied if no rule applies.
        // Process file in Sources/Example/Resources/*
        .process("Resources"),
      ]),
    .testTarget(
      name: "ExampleTests",
      dependencies: [Example],
      resources: [
        // Copy Tests/ExampleTests/Resources directories as-is. 
        // Use to retain directory structure.
        // Will be at top level in bundle.
        .copy("Resources"),
      ]),
```

**Reported Issues & Possible Workarounds**

- [Swift 5.3 SPM Resources in tests uses wrong bundle path?](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-5-3-spm-resources-in-tests-uses-wrong-bundle-path/37051)
- [Swift Package Manager - Resources in test targets](https://github.com/Nef10/SPMResourcesInTest)

**Xcode**

*`Bundle.module` is generated by SwiftPM (see [Build/BuildPlan.swift SwiftTargetBuildDescription generateResourceAccessor()](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Sources/Build/BuildPlan.swift)) and thus not present in [Foundation.Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) when built by Xcode.*

A comparable approach in Xcode would be to:

1. manually add a `Resources` reference folder to the Xcode project,
2. add an Xcode build  phase `copy` to put the `Resource` into some `*.bundle` directory,
3. add a some custom `#ifdef XCODE_BUILD` compiler directive for the Xcode build to work with the resources.

```swift
#if XCODE_BUILD
extension Foundation.Bundle {
    
    /// Returns resource bundle as a `Bundle`.
    /// Requires Xcode copy phase to locate files into `ExecutableName.bundle`;
    /// or `ExecutableNameTests.bundle` for test resources
    static var module: Bundle = {
        var thisModuleName = "CLIQuickstartLib"
        var url = Bundle.main.bundleURL
        
        for bundle in Bundle.allBundles where bundle.bundlePath.hasSuffix(".xctest") {
            url = bundle.bundleURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
            thisModuleName = thisModuleName.appending("Tests")
        }
        
        url = url.appendingPathComponent("\(thisModuleName).bundle")
        
        guard let bundle = Bundle(url: url) else {
            fatalError("Foundation.Bundle.module could not load resource bundle: \(url.path)")
        }
        
        return bundle
    }()
    
    /// Directory containing resource bundle
    static var moduleDir: URL = {
        var url = Bundle.main.bundleURL
        for bundle in Bundle.allBundles where bundle.bundlePath.hasSuffix(".xctest") {
            // remove 'ExecutableNameTests.xctest' path component
            url = bundle.bundleURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
        }
        return url
    }()
    
}
#endif
```

Comment: Ironically `#if Xcode` is defined for SwiftPM now. It would need to be a custom flag, like `#if NOT_IN_SPM`. Apple really need to find a solution that allows Bundle.module in both regular Xcode projects and SPM

Comment: To access files in a test bundle, I've had to use `let url = Bundle.module.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("ExampleFiles/example.url")` -- I gave the directory `ExampleFiles` in the `.copy` in Package.swift.
`

Comment: I've noticed a difference in the way the Package.swift resource `.copy` responds on Mac OS versus Ubuntu if the files are sym links (created with `ln -s`). On Mac OS, a copy of the file contents are created (what I wanted). On Ubuntu, it creates a copy of the sym link itself (not useful in my case because the sym link I have is relative, and working under Docker/Ubuntu breaks the link).

Comment: A better way to find the copied resource is `Bundle.module.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: nil, subdirectory: "Resources")`. That deals with different bundle layouts produced on different platforms.

Comment: Note that perhaps there's some bug when using `.copy(…)` Resources. I couldn't get it to compile - something to do with code signing. `.process(…)` does work, though, and it's perfect because I don't have to worry about the folder structure anymore (since it flattens it all out).

Answer (score 37):

SwiftPM (5.1) does not support resources natively [yet](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-pm-bundles-and-resources/13981), however...

When unit tests are running, the repository can be expected to be available, so simply load the resource with something derived from `#file`. This works with all extant versions of SwiftPM.

```swift
let thisSourceFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file)
let thisDirectory = thisSourceFile.deletingLastPathComponent()
let resourceURL = thisDirectory.appendingPathComponent("TestAudio.m4a")
```

---

In cases other than tests, where the repository will not be around at runtime, resources can still be included, albeit at the expense of the binary size. Any arbitrary file can be embedded into Swift source by expressing it as base 64 data in a string literal. [Workspace](https://sdggiesbrecht.github.io/Workspace)  is an open‐source tool that can automate that process: `$ workspace refresh resources`. <sup>(Disclaimer: I am its author.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that just made my day. Could include a `testFiles.bundle` into my unit tests.

Comment: Best answer - simple and clean

Answer (score 32):

**Bundle.module** started to work for me after right file structure and dependencies setup.

#### File structure for test target:

[image]

#### Dependencies setup in Package.swift:

```
targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .target(
        name: "Parser",
        dependencies: []),
    .testTarget(
        name: "ParserTests",
        dependencies: ["Parser"],
        resources: [
            .copy("Resources/test.txt")
        ]
    ),
]
```

#### Usage in the project:

```
private var testData: Data {
    let url = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "txt")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    return data
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (tested on Swift 5.5). Hugal31 can you update the "correct answer" badge?

Comment: Note that `Bundle.module` won't exist until you add a resource *that can be found* in Package.swift.

Answer (score 4):

*A Swift script approach for Swift 5.2 and earlier...*

### Swift Package Manager (SwiftPM)

It is possible to use resources in unit tests with SwiftPM for both macOS and Linux with some additional setup and custom scripts. Here is a description of one possible approach:

*The SwiftPM does not yet provide a mechanism for handling resources.  The following is a workable approach for using test resources `TestResources/` within a package; and, also provides for a consistent `TestScratch/` directory for creating test files if needed.*

### Setup:

- Add test resources directory `TestResources/` in the `PackageName/` directory.
- For Xcode use, add test resources to project "Build Phases" for the test bundle target.

  - Project Editor > TARGETS > CxSQLiteFrameworkTests > Build Phases > Copy Files: Destination Resources, `+` add files
- For command line use, set up Bash aliases which include  swift-copy-testresources.swift
- Place an executable version of swift-copy-testresources.swift on an appropriate path which is included $PATH.

  - Ubuntu: `nano ~/bin/ swift-copy-testresources.swift`

**Bash Aliases**

*macOS: `nano .bash_profile`*

```bash
alias swiftbuild='swift-copy-testresources.swift $PWD; swift build -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-macosx10.13";'
alias swifttest='swift-copy-testresources.swift $PWD; swift test -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-macosx10.13";'
alias swiftxcode='swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Package.xcconfig; echo "REMINDER: set Xcode build system."'
```

*Ubuntu: `nano ~/.profile`. Apppend to end. Change /opt/swift/current to where Swift is installed for a given system.*

```bash
#############
### SWIFT ###
#############
if [ -d "/opt/swift/current/usr/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="/opt/swift/current/usr/bin:$PATH"
fi

alias swiftbuild='swift-copy-testresources.swift $PWD; swift build;'
alias swifttest='swift-copy-testresources.swift $PWD; swift test;'
```

**Script: swift-copy-testresources.sh** `chmod +x`

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift

// FILE: swift-copy-testresources.sh
// verify swift path with "which -a swift"
// macOS: /usr/bin/swift 
// Ubuntu: /opt/swift/current/usr/bin/swift 
import Foundation

func copyTestResources() {
    let argv = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
    // for i in 0..<argv.count {
    //     print("argv[\(i)] = \(argv[i])")
    // }
    let pwd = argv[argv.count-1]
    print("Executing swift-copy-testresources")
    print("  PWD=\(pwd)")
    
    let fm = FileManager.default
    
    let pwdUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: pwd, isDirectory: true)
    let srcUrl = pwdUrl
        .appendingPathComponent("TestResources", isDirectory: true)
    let buildUrl = pwdUrl
        .appendingPathComponent(".build", isDirectory: true)
    let dstUrl = buildUrl
        .appendingPathComponent("Contents", isDirectory: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("Resources", isDirectory: true)
    
    do {
        let contents = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: srcUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: [])
        do { try fm.removeItem(at: dstUrl) } catch { }
        try fm.createDirectory(at: dstUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
        for fromUrl in contents {
            try fm.copyItem(
                at: fromUrl, 
                to: dstUrl.appendingPathComponent(fromUrl.lastPathComponent)
            )
        }
    } catch {
        print("  SKIP TestResources not copied. ")
        return
    }
            
    print("  SUCCESS TestResources copy completed.\n  FROM \(srcUrl)\n  TO \(dstUrl)")
}

copyTestResources()
```

**Test Utility Code**

```swift
////////////////
// MARK: - Linux
//////////////// 
#if os(Linux)

// /PATH_TO_PACKAGE/PackageName/.build/TestResources
func getTestResourcesUrl() -> URL? {
    guard let packagePath = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PWD"]
        else { return nil }
    let packageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: packagePath)
    let testResourcesUrl = packageUrl
        .appendingPathComponent(".build", isDirectory: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("TestResources", isDirectory: true)
    return testResourcesUrl
} 

// /PATH_TO_PACKAGE/PackageName/.build/TestScratch
func getTestScratchUrl() -> URL? {
    guard let packagePath = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PWD"]
        else { return nil }
    let packageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: packagePath)
    let testScratchUrl = packageUrl
        .appendingPathComponent(".build")
        .appendingPathComponent("TestScratch")
    return testScratchUrl
}

// /PATH_TO_PACKAGE/PackageName/.build/TestScratch
func resetTestScratch() throws {
    if let testScratchUrl = getTestScratchUrl() {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        do {_ = try fm.removeItem(at: testScratchUrl)} catch {}
        _ = try fm.createDirectory(at: testScratchUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    }
}

///////////////////
// MARK: - macOS
///////////////////
#elseif os(macOS)

func isXcodeTestEnvironment() -> Bool {
    let arg0 = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[0]
    // Use arg0.hasSuffix("/usr/bin/xctest") for command line environment
    return arg0.hasSuffix("/Xcode/Agents/xctest")
}

// /PATH_TO/PackageName/TestResources
func getTestResourcesUrl() -> URL? {
    let testBundle = Bundle(for: CxSQLiteFrameworkTests.self)
    let testBundleUrl = testBundle.bundleURL
    
    if isXcodeTestEnvironment() { // test via Xcode 
        let testResourcesUrl = testBundleUrl
            .appendingPathComponent("Contents", isDirectory: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("Resources", isDirectory: true)
        return testResourcesUrl            
    }
    else { // test via command line
        guard let packagePath = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PWD"]
            else { return nil }
        let packageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: packagePath)
        let testResourcesUrl = packageUrl
            .appendingPathComponent(".build", isDirectory: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("TestResources", isDirectory: true)
        return testResourcesUrl
    }
} 

func getTestScratchUrl() -> URL? {
    let testBundle = Bundle(for: CxSQLiteFrameworkTests.self)
    let testBundleUrl = testBundle.bundleURL
    if isXcodeTestEnvironment() {
        return testBundleUrl
            .deletingLastPathComponent()
            .appendingPathComponent("TestScratch")
    }
    else {
        return testBundleUrl
            .deletingLastPathComponent()
            .deletingLastPathComponent()
            .deletingLastPathComponent()
            .appendingPathComponent("TestScratch")
    }
}

func resetTestScratch() throws {
    if let testScratchUrl = getTestScratchUrl() {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        do {_ = try fm.removeItem(at: testScratchUrl)} catch {}
        _ = try fm.createDirectory(at: testScratchUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    }
}

#endif
```

### File Locations:

**Linux**

During the `swift build` and `swift test` the process environment variable `PWD` provides a path the package root `…/PackageName`. The `PackageName/TestResources/` files are copied to `$PWD/.buid/TestResources`. The `TestScratch/` directory, if used during test runtime, is created in `$PWD/.buid/TestScratch`.

```
.build/
├── debug -> x86_64-unknown-linux/debug
...
├── TestResources
│   └── SomeTestResource.sql      <-- (copied from TestResources/)
├── TestScratch
│   └── SomeTestProduct.sqlitedb  <-- (created by running tests)
└── x86_64-unknown-linux
    └── debug
        ├── PackageName.build/
        │   └── ...
        ├── PackageNamePackageTests.build
        │   └── ...
        ├── PackageNamePackageTests.swiftdoc
        ├── PackageNamePackageTests.swiftmodule
        ├── PackageNamePackageTests.xctest  <-- executable, not Bundle
        ├── PackageName.swiftdoc
        ├── PackageName.swiftmodule
        ├── PackageNameTests.build
        │   └── ...
        ├── PackageNameTests.swiftdoc
        ├── PackageNameTests.swiftmodule
        └── ModuleCache ...
```

**macOS CLI**

```
.build/
|-- TestResources/
|   `-- SomeTestResource.sql      <-- (copied from TestResources/)
|-- TestScratch/
|   `-- SomeTestProduct.sqlitedb  <-- (created by running tests)
...
|-- debug -> x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug
`-- x86_64-apple-macosx10.10
    `-- debug
        |-- PackageName.build/
        |-- PackageName.swiftdoc
        |-- PackageName.swiftmodule
        |-- PackageNamePackageTests.xctest
        |   `-- Contents
        |       `-- MacOS
        |           |-- PackageNamePackageTests
        |           `-- PackageNamePackageTests.dSYM
        ...
        `-- libPackageName.a
```

**macOS Xcode**

`PackageName/TestResources/` files are copied into the test bundle `Contents/Resources` folder as part of the Build Phases. If used during tests, `TestScratch/` is placed alongside the `*xctest` bundle.

```
Build/Products/Debug/
|-- PackageNameTests.xctest/
|   `-- Contents/
|       |-- Frameworks/
|       |   |-- ...
|       |   `-- libswift*.dylib
|       |-- Info.plist
|       |-- MacOS/
|       |   `-- PackageNameTests
|       `-- Resources/               <-- (aka TestResources/)
|           |-- SomeTestResource.sql <-- (copied from TestResources/)
|           `-- libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
`-- TestScratch/
    `-- SomeTestProduct.sqlitedb     <-- (created by running tests)
```

I also posted a GitHubGist of this same approach at [004.4'2 SW Dev Swift Package Manager (SPM) With Resources Qref](https://gist.github.com/marc-medley/599d387337e29c74624816a57f2e4c12)

Answer (score 3):

starting on Swift 5.3, thanks to [SE-0271](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0271-package-manager-resources.md), you can add bundle resources on swift package manager by adding `resources` on your `.target` declaration.

example:

```
.target(
   name: "HelloWorldProgram",
   dependencies: [], 
   resources: [.process(Images), .process("README.md")]
)
```

if you want to learn more, I have written an article on [medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-add-resources-in-swift-package-manager-c437d44ec593), discussing this topic. I don't specifically discuss `.testTarget`, but looking on the swift proposal, it looks alike.

Comment: Pro top: Use private window in your browser to get past the medium paywall, oh medium 

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution looking at [this file](https://github.com/ustwo/mockingbird/blob/master/Sources/ResourceKit/Helpers/ResourceHandler.swift).

It's possible to create a bundle with a path, for example:

```
let currentBundle = Bundle.allBundles.filter() { $0.bundlePath.hasSuffix(".xctest") }.first!
let realBundle = Bundle(path: "\(currentBundle.bundlePath)/../../../../Tests/MyProjectTests/Resources")
```

It's a bit ugly, but if you want to avoid a Makefile, it works.

Comment: Note two issues with this solution:
1. Your code has to depend on the directory structure and on where the resources are located. Using Makefile, you make the code independent of the current implementation of resource handling in Swift, and you put this knowledge in Makefile. If resource handling changes, you change the Makefile, not the code.
2. You have to create Bundle with different path parameters  - in tests vs in code, on Linux and on Mac. Makefile can put the resources in the correct locations, in all the environments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```swift
extension Bundle {
    func locateFirst(forResource: String, withExtension: String) -> URL? {
        for b in Bundle.allBundles {
            if let u = b.url(forResource: forResource, withExtension: withExtension) {
                return u
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

And then just call locateFirst, which gives the first item.
like:

```swift
let p12 = Bundle().locateFirst(forResource: "Certificates", withExtension: "p12")!
```

Comment: Or even simpler: ```Bundle.allBundles.compactMap {$0.url(forResource: "Certificates", withExtension: "p12") }```

Answer (score -1):

A made a simple solution that works for legacy swift and future swift:

1. Add your assets in the root of your project
2. In your swift code: `ResourceHelper.projectRootURL(projectRef: #file, fileName: "temp.bundle/payload.json").path`
3. Works in Xcode and swift build in terminal or github actions 
   https://eon.codes/blog/2020/01/04/How-to-include-assets-with-swift-package-manager/ and https://github.com/eonist/ResourceHelper/