# "Interrupted system call" when reading test data in XCTestCase

Tags: swift, xcode

Using Xcode (11.4.1) on Catalina (10.15.4, only updated from Mojave 5 days ago), with a tiny SPM-based project opened in Xcode in "folder mode" (i.e. not an actual `.xcodeproj`), I have a test which should read some input data from a sample file. Following [recommendations for constructing a URL to those files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58034307/325366), `Data(contentsOf:)` cannot read it, although the generated URL is correct.

The code is:

```
func testCanReadConfigFromFile() {
    let thisDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file)
        .deletingLastPathComponent()

    let url = thisDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent("Test_data", isDirectory: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("Config.json", isDirectory: false)

    print(url.absoluteString)

    do {
        let _ = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “Config.json” couldn’t be opened."
UserInfo={NSFilePath=/full/path/to/project/Tests/ProjectTests/Test_data/Config.json,
NSUnderlyingError=0x100b0aa30
{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=4 "Interrupted system call"}}
```

If I take the string output by `print(url.absoluteString)` and in a terminal execute `file <absoulteString>`, it confirms that my file does exist at that path (and that it is JSON).

"Interrupted system call" makes me think Catalina's stricter sand-boxing rules are to blame, but I have not been shown a permissions dialog. This project is within my ~/Documents folder, which Xcode does have permission to read.

**Edited to add:**

`swift test` at the command line works. It's only running tests in Xcode that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report? https://bugs.swift.org

Comment: Temporary solution, but trying twice worked for me `let data = try (try? Data(contentsOf: url)) ?? (Data(contentsOf: url))`